# Find & Change (Ctrl+F) - in Grep mode: space+questionmark to just questionmark in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, formatting

How do i find and change space + questionmark in GREP mode in InDesign. It seems the intuitive way by just typing in those two characters in the Search-bar (Ctrl+f) doesn't seem to work. Also the spaces special character doesn't work for me. Any hints on how to do it properly?

Comment: What "Search-bar?" A web browser search bar? Your File Manager search bar? This forum's Search Q&A bar at the top right corner of the screen? A mobile app search bar? The answer you seek may depend on the environment you are experiencing trouble in.

Comment: "The Title is rather selfexplanatory." I'm afraid it is not to me. Please [edit] your question and try to explain what you tried, why it did not do what you expected and what it was you expected. Do not expect from us to try and replicate your problems, we don't have the time and, frankly, why should we be bothered if you can't?

Comment: err... find and replace (ctrl+f)? Maybe its not a space at all.. Then use grep "\s[?]"

Comment: Yes Ctrl+F "Suchen und ersetzen" in german... Sorry for the bad translation. I have tried Grep and Text Options and both to no avail.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, the question is already clearer. I withdrew my -1.

Answer (score 7):

Use GREP search query.
Search for **\s\?**
Replace by **?**
Check the target of your query (document, story or selection). This is probably why you couldn't make it work properly.
See example below of a couple of different kinds of spaces that would be affected:

[image]

Comment: This did it... for some strange reason did Indesign write "\s" instead of "\s\" if space is chosen through the menu. Typing it in by hand works fine. Thank you !

Comment: \s stands for "any space" while \? stands for "question mark". ? character has a special meaning in Grep query, so you either need to "escape" it using backslash (like I did) or put it in a class like this: [?], just like Jooja suggested.

Comment: thanks i haven had too much experience with that before, so i learned something new today :)

Comment: have a look at http://www.ericagamet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Erica-Gamets-GREP-Cheat-Sheet.pdf

Comment: @Lucian naah never leave home without [Regular Expression Pocket Reference](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596514273.do)

Answer (score 0):

The standard search box (top right) does indeed seem to have some kind of issue with locating  `[SPACE]?` but if you use the standard Find/Change dialogue <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> it works fine. Just make sure to select "Forward", or "Backward" depending on your cursor location in the document.

In fact I've never even noticed that search box before, and can't confirm what it does!

Comment: ..a special thanks for leaving the word GREP out of your self explanatory title until edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script called "Use my Typo" that let you put/delete space after/before any character and many others (like delete multiple spaces)

also in the search/replace window if you put space using the space button it don't work. You need to use symbol for space, like "^m"